# How to : a brief intro to scaling and rescaling data ( inputs) for supervised learning algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, svm, neural-networks, normalization, multidimensional-scaling

I understand the concept of scaling and that it improves results in SVM's and NN's.
however I would like to find somewhere where is is explained, in easy "layman's terms" terms. of how it is done. I would rather it not be Wikipedia as I am using it for my masters thesis.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it is for your thesis and you already understand it, I recommend you write that text yourself. If you have specific questions though, many people here are happy to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very nice article that you can look at for more info on implementation (http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part2/section-16.html)

Comment: Ha, I had posted this for a few other questions and then found this Q&A.  I second this as a great resource.  It helps explain things very well.  Also there are many other sections that would probably help to understand other aspects of machine learning.